# Image hashing in c++, with similar images feature

Tags: c++, image, hash, memoization

I'm developing a [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) system for similar images. I will divide this question in two subquestions since one is the next step of the other, but I could post two different questions if you think that's more appropriate.

**First thing to know:** I don't know nothing about image processing, so please be gentle with this poor guy :)

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

We have a function `ReturnType foo(Image)` that takes an image, make some time expensive computation on it and it returns something (which depends on the application). The memoizator that I'm designing is an `unordered_map<ImageHash,ReturnType>` (or an equivalent structure), so if the user submit the same image twice, it returns directly the already computed `ReturnType` value.

**WHAT I NEED**

As you can imagine, I need some `HashFunction` s.t. `HashFunction(Image)=ImageHash`, where `ImageHash` is unique with high probability.

Notice that this `ImageHash` **must** not depend on the particular run, machine, time. This because the `unordered_map` will be serialized on file (so it can be used in different runs) and by shared with other users.

Since performance is really crucial, a fast hash function would be good.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336209/fast-and-simple-image-hashing-algorithm) about the topic, but the author introduces a lot of constraints on the image (and in addiction no good solution is given).

**Note:** There is no constraint on the image, so you can propose any solution you prefer (include the set of image that it's designed for).

**Note:** could be SHA-1 a possible solution? I used it only for strings, I don't know if it possible to use it for images (and if it exists a C++ implementation)

**THE NEXT STEP**

I would like to extend the previous solution so we return the same result for **similar images**. So formally, given `Image image1` similar to `Image image2`, then the system returns `ReturnType result` for `image1` if `(image1,result)` **OR** `(image2,result)` were already previously computed.

I've heard about [phash](http://www.phash.org/) but I don't know if it's suitable for this purpose.

Comment: md5 is a common hash algorithm for this sort of thing.  As far as using hashing to match similar images, I don't think that is going to work -- hash codes are very much dependent on the exact sequence of bytes used to generate them, and there is not (to my knowledge) any way to use them to test for inexact-equality.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner So sha-1 is good also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you first start to gather some images before proceeding any further. Having said that, the best way to do it currently is to learn a similarity function using deep learning and map the image into some n-dimensional feature space and use cosine distance to measure similarity. Here's some example code to get you started (https://github.com/kevinlin311tw/caffe-cvprw15). If you want a more performant technique and is willing to follow the rabbit hole, look into triplet ranking loss.

Phash works yes but it's performance in producing a similarity score is far below that of using deep learning features. However, it definitely better than real hashing techniques because just a change of jpeg compression level is going to change the hash value. If you don't want to spend too much time on this, phash would be the best possible alternative as it takes no effort to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's well appreciated. Can you explain me how can I create some n-dimensional vector from an image? I think this is the basic for such a process :)

Answer (score 0):

I just have a little sidenote in case you use the stl `unordered_map`

Caching the results of the computation will not work if you are using `unordered_map<ImageHash,ReturnType>` with the result of the hash as the key. If two images hash to the same value, an insert with the second image will not happen.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/

> Each element is inserted only if its key is not equivalent to the key of any other element already in the container (keys in an unordered_map are unique).

The key needs to be of the type `Image` so that hash collisions can be properly handled by `unordered_map`.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

```
template < class Key,                                    // unordered_map::key_type
           class T,                                      // unordered_map::mapped_type
           class Hash = hash<Key>,                       // unordered_map::hasher
           class Pred = equal_to<Key>,                   // unordered_map::key_equal
           class Alloc = allocator< pair<const Key,T> >  // unordered_map::allocator_type
           > class unordered_map;
```

You will need to provide a `hash<key>` argument if you end up using the stl `unordered_map` and let `unordered_map` call the hash function instead of using the result of a hash function you call as the key.

Comment: Updated: `ImageHash` must be unique with high probability.

Comment: @justHelloWorld I guess I don't see a reason why you would not just let unordered_map do its thing, you can even get the hashed value from unordered_map if you need that